# Cannot add new items into list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, ejs

I'm currently grappling with an issue related to JavaScript, particularly involving the addition of new items to a list dynamically. In my project, I've developed a web-based form using .ejs templates and Node.js. The form is closely tied to an Excel file functioning as a database. Each sheet within the Excel file corresponds to a distinct category, and it ask user inputs in the form if they did not find the option they are looking for. It should generate a 22-digit code for each category.

The issue lies in the JavaScript functionality responsible for this dynamic addition. Despite my best efforts, the system fails to locate the input element needed for adding new items and generating the corresponding codes. This results in the inability to save the newly generated codes to the Excel file and subsequently update the form.

Thank you in advance for your time and support!

ejs part of my script where error is:

```
 function addNew(sheetName) {
  console.log('addNew called with sheetName:', sheetName);

  const newInput = document.getElementById(`new${sheetName}`);
  console.log('newInput element:', newInput);

  if (!newInput) {
    console.log(`Input element for ${sheetName} not found.`);
    return;
  }

  const inputValue = newInput.value;
  console.log('Input value:', inputValue);

  if (!inputValue.trim()) {
    console.log('Input is empty. Not adding to the sheet.');
    return;
  }

      // Send the data to the server using Axios AJAX request
      axios.post('/add', { sheetName, newInput })
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Data added successfully:', response.data);

          // Update the current page with the newly added data
          const newRow = `<tr><td>${newInput}</td><td>${response.data.code}</td></tr>`;
          const tableBody = document.getElementById(`${sheetName.toLowerCase()}TableBody`);
          tableBody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow);

          // Clear the input field after adding
          document.getElementById(`new${sheetName}`).value = '';
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error adding data:', error);
        });
    }
```

I've meticulously reviewed the code, verified the alignment between input element IDs and sheet names, and confirmed the sequence of HTML rendering and script execution. Additionally, I've integrated console.log statements to track data flow and pinpoint the source of the problem. However, the root cause of the issue still eludes me.

Moreover,  I am also sturggling to get rid of Content Security Policy. Even after multple attempts and solutions from internet it is not going away.

Screenshot of errors:

[image: Screenshot of errors]

Comment: How is `addNew` called? I would disable plugins in the browser to verify it is not them screwing up the call.

Comment: The addNew function in my code is called when a user clicks the 'Add' button on the form. This function is responsible for adding new data to the Excel sheet, acting as a pseudo-database, through an AJAX request to the server. The purpose is to dynamically update the sheet with new entries based on the user's input

Comment: And you cancel the form submission?

Comment: Yes, I am canceling the form submission to avoid page reloads and use AJAX for smooth updates.

Comment: Cool, so I would suggest running in incognito mode to verify that no extensions are killing the connection. Seen that error with extensions like ad blocker and tamper monkey.